# Basic Auth in htaccess... only if in a specific subpath

Tags: .htaccess, http-basic-authentication

We deploy the same code with the same `.htaccess` to *Integration*, *Stage* and *Production*.

I want to require a basic auth on all but the *Production* server.

They differ in the path, e.g. `/data/stage/www/...` vs. `/data/prod/www/...`

Comment: Then don't deploy a .htaccess file at all but mandate authentication from the main apache configuration

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask].

Comment: What is the document root in each case? And where is the `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: Presumably, the hostname also differs for each server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this does sound like something you should be doing in the server config, rather than `.htaccess`.

However, this can be done in `.htaccess` using an Apache expression (Apache 2.4+) to test whether the `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable does not start with `/data/prod/www/` (ie. the request has not resolved to the *Production* server).

For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !~ m#^/data/prod/www/#">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted"
    AuthUserFile "/path/to/passwd/.htpasswd"
    Require valid-user
</If>
```